# How the setup the environment of MIT-Scheme with slimv in windows 7?

Tags: slimv

I read the source code of `slimv\ftplugin\scheme\slimv-scheme.vim`

```
    if exists( 'g:scheme_builtin_swank' ) && g:scheme_builtin_swank
        " MIT Scheme contains a built-in swank server since version 9.1.1
        return 'scheme --eval "(let loop () (start-swank) (loop))"'
    endif
```

There's no `scheme.exe` in my system, only find one `c:\Program Files\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe`

When I tried to run `C:\Program Files\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin>mit-scheme.exe  --eval "(let loop () (start-
swank) (loop))"`, there's an error

```
---------------------------
MIT/GNU Scheme terminating
---------------------------
scheme: can't find a readable default for option --band.
    searched for file all.com in these directories:
    c:\local\mit-scheme
Reason for termination:
Inconsistency detected.
---------------------------
```

I have tried to load one .scm in Vim and type this command:

```
:echo SlimvSwankCommand()
```

And the autodetection was unsuccessful:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a command that runs a swank server inside MIT Scheme.
Let's suppose that Scheme is installed in the `MIT-GNU Scheme` directory on Windows.
You also need a swank server for MIT Scheme, e.g. `swank-mit-scheme.scm` in slimv (taken from SLIME).
Then you start MIT Scheme from the command prompt and load the swank server this way:

`"C:\Program Files\MIT-GNU Scheme\mit-scheme" --band "C:\Program Files\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib\all.com" --library "C:\Program Files\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib" --load "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\slime\contrib\swank-mit-scheme.scm"`

If you want slimv to run it for you upon pressing `,c` then you need to embed the above command in `'!start /MIN ...'` and pass it to `g:slimv_swank_scheme` in your `_vimrc` (remember to enclose each path that contains space in double quotes):

`let g:slimv_swank_scheme='!start /MIN "C:\Program Files\MIT-GNU Scheme\mit-scheme" --band "C:\Program Files\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib\all.com" --library "C:\Program Files\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib" --load "C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\slime\contrib\swank-mit-scheme.scm"'`

Of course you can use another swank server as well. The main point is to pass the full path to each component in the above command. I suggest that first you try to run the swank server manually from the command prompt. When it's okay you can put it into `'!start /MIN ...'`.